# add hostgroup instead of overwriting it

Tags: nagios

In my nagios configuration, hosts that use a specific template are automatically added to a hostgroup, so my configuration looks something like this:

```
define host {
    name          foo
    ...
    hostgroups    bar
    register 0
}

define host {
    name          baz
    use           foo
}
```

But now I want to add host `baz` also to another hostgroup. I know, I can do this in the hostgroup, but is there a way to do it in the host? I think of something like this:

```
define host {
    name          baz
    use           foo
    hostgroups    <hostgroupsYouAreAlreadyIn>,another-hostgroup
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From memory,

```
hostgroups +another-hostgroup
```

Should do the trick.  I believe that *anywhere* Nagios allows a list of values, you can use a `+` prefix to append to the inherited list, instead of resetting it.